# Zend 2 framework form helper method openTag is converting my action to htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

This is straight out of "Zend Framework 2.0 by Example" by Krishna Shasankar V, which I am currently working through. I am using ZF version 2.3.2. I am running this in a standalone installation in a user directory, which seems to be a rather unusual set up. I have googled all about and asked on #zftalk on irc:freenode. No response there. This is in Ch. 3, pg 42. It is part of a registration form. I've found many other use examples of the Zend 2 framework form helpers, and this does not deviate from them significantly as far as I can see:

---

```
<?php 
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' => 'process')));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
```

---

This is in a view, of course.

The problem is that the line:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' => 'process')));
```

results in the action attribute (and others) of the form having html special character codes for the slashes and ~ characters, which makes the form unsubmittable:

---

```
<form action="&#x2F;&#x7E;zend2test&#x2F;users&#x2F;Register&#x2F;process" method="post" name="Register" enctype="multipart&#x2F;form-data" id="Register">
```

---

I modified the view source to this to check if the problem was the string returned by url():

---

```
$action = $this->url(NULL,array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' => 'process'));

echo $action;

$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $action);
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
```

---

Which resulted in this output:

---

```
/~zend2test/users/Register/process 

<form action="&#x2F;&#x7E;zend2test&#x2F;users&#x2F;Register&#x2F;process" method="post" name="Register" enctype="multipart&#x2F;form-data" id="Register">
```

---

The output of the $action string is correct. That is what the form action should be.

I also echoed out $form->getAttribute('action'), which output the correct, un-encoded string.

So it appears to be the opentag() method that is adding the special character codes. How can I stop it from doing that? I've tried setting the $action string statically with similar results. I tried setting it statically leaving the "~" off. It still converted the "/" characters. There is another form in the example application that I'm working on that has the same problem. I've tried using htmlspecialchars_decode() with no effect.

Comment: This is a known issue, but the result is perfectly valid HTML, and shouldn't in any way affect how the form functions.

Comment: A discussion on github: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6461

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem now. The form was not submitting and since the encoded action attribute seemed weird to me, I focused on that as the likely problem. Of course the reason that it is not submitting is that the "submit" button is not of type "submit." I assume that as I work through this tutorial a submit action will be attached to it with javascript or something, but just to check I changed the type and it does submit. Sure is an ugly attribute sting though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non issue. There were other problems with the form. If anyone else is interested in, as bitWorking says, see https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6461